# POST error 500 - jersey 2 rest api application

Tags: rest, maven, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, java-11

Problem

I have a simple rest application with low complexity built using jersey 2. I use maven for dependency management. I was getting cors issue with post request(JSON) from angular app. It was working fine with other content type except for json payloads. requests with json data was working fine in  postman. Then I created a CORSFilter. Now the error is changed and everything is stopped working.

I need

- to find whether my project setup is correct or not
- to find what the blunder I have done
- send post request from angular app with json data and get response

Project deployment assembly

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lq6pc.jpg

Project facets
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XdlQ.jpg

My project structure
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lbEO.jpg

I have followed so many suggestions and workarounds. Maybe I was wrongly following them.

My pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>OnlineOrganicMarket</groupId>
    <artifactId>OnlineOrganicMarket</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <jersey2.version>2.27</jersey2.version>
        <jaxrs.version>2.1</jaxrs.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20160810</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JAX-RS -->
        <dependency> <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId> <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId> 
            <version>${jaxrs.version}</version> </dependency>
        <!-- Jersey 2.19 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId> <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId> 
            <version>${jersey2.version}</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId> 
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId> <version>${jersey2.version}</version> 
            </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>2.26-b03</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.27</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>2.27</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-json-org</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.15</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

My web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">
  <display-name>OnlineOrganicMarket</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.oom.services</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <!-- <servlet>
    <description>JAX-RS Tools Generated - Do not modify</description>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/jaxrs/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping> -->

</web-app>
```

CORS filter

```
package com.oom.services.filter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javax.annotation.Priority;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.HttpMethod;
import javax.ws.rs.Priorities;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ExtendedUriInfo;

@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.HEADER_DECORATOR)
public class CORSFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter {
 private static final String ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials";
 private static final String ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS = "Access-Control-Allow-Headers";
 private static final String ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_METHODS = "Access-Control-Allow-Methods";
 private static final String ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin";
 private static final String ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS = "Access-Control-Request-Headers";
 private static final String AUTHORIZATION = "authorization";
 private static final String ORIGIN = "Origin";

 private static String extractAllowedMethods(final ExtendedUriInfo extendedUriInfo) {
  final Optional<Class<?>> optional = extendedUriInfo.getMatchedRuntimeResources().stream()
    .flatMap(r -> r.getResources().stream()).flatMap(r -> r.getHandlerClasses().stream())
    .filter(r -> r.getPackage().getName().startsWith("com.oom.services")).findFirst();

  if (optional.isPresent()) {
   return Arrays.stream(optional.get().getDeclaredMethods())//
     .flatMap(m -> Arrays.stream(m.getAnnotations()))//
     .map(a -> a.annotationType().getAnnotation(javax.ws.rs.HttpMethod.class))//
     .filter(Objects::nonNull)//
     .map(HttpMethod::value)//
     .distinct()//
     .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
  }
  // Returning OPTIONS is a bit shady, as ACAM is about *real*, actual methods only.
  return "OPTIONS";
 }

 @Context
 private HttpServletRequest request;

 @Context
 private ExtendedUriInfo extendedUriInfo;

 @Override
 public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
  final String origin = requestContext.getHeaderString(ORIGIN);
  if (origin != null && "OPTIONS".equals(requestContext.getMethod())) {
   request.setAttribute(this.getClass().getName(), true);
   requestContext.abortWith(Response.ok("CORS OK, carry on.", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE).build());
  }
 }

 /**
  * @see https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/
  * @see https://jmchung.github.io/blog/2013/08/11/cross-domain-on-jersey-restful-web-services/
  * @see https://solutionsisee.wordpress.com/2016/06/30/adding-cors-support-in-jersey-server/
  */
 @Override
 public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext, final ContainerResponseContext responseContext)
   throws IOException {

  final MultivaluedMap<String, Object> responseHeaders = responseContext.getHeaders();
  final String origin = requestContext.getHeaderString(ORIGIN);

  if (origin != null) {
   // The presence of the Origin header marks a CORS request.
   responseHeaders.add(ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN, origin);
   responseHeaders.add(ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_METHODS, extractAllowedMethods(extendedUriInfo));
   responseHeaders.add(ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS, AUTHORIZATION + ", X-Requested-With, Content-Type");
   if (requestContext.getHeaderString(ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS) != null) {
    responseHeaders.add(ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS, requestContext
      .getHeaderString(ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS).toLowerCase().contains(AUTHORIZATION));
   }
  }

  if (request.getAttribute(this.getClass().getName()) != null) {
   // We are in a CORS Preflight answer, fast tracked. The entity (== response body) is not
   // relevant.
  }
 }
}
```

Currently getting this error

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><title>HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error</title><style type="text/css">h1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} h2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} h3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} b {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} p {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} a.name {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}</style></head><body><h1>HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error</h1><hr class="line" /><p><b>Type</b> Exception Report</p><p><b>Message</b> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com&#47;fasterxml&#47;jackson&#47;core&#47;filter&#47;TokenFilter</p><p><b>Description</b> The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.</p><p><b>Exception</b></p><pre>javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com&#47;fasterxml&#47;jackson&#47;core&#47;filter&#47;TokenFilter
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:432)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
</pre><p><b>Root Cause</b></p><pre>org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com&#47;fasterxml&#47;jackson&#47;core&#47;filter&#47;TokenFilter
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.rethrow(ResponseWriter.java:278)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.failure(ResponseWriter.java:260)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:460)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:285)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
</pre><p><b>Root Cause</b></p><pre>java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com&#47;fasterxml&#47;jackson&#47;core&#47;filter&#47;TokenFilter
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._newReader(ObjectMapper.java:640)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.reader(ObjectMapper.java:3323)
    org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.internal.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase._configForReading(ProviderBase.java:489)
    org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.internal.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase._endpointForReading(ProviderBase.java:882)
    org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.internal.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase.readFrom(ProviderBase.java:789)
    org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.invokeReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:257)
    org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:236)
    org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:156)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:73)
    org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:156)
    org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1091)
    org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:874)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest.readEntity(ContainerRequest.java:271)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.EntityParamValueParamProvider$EntityValueSupplier.apply(EntityParamValueParamProvider.java:97)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.EntityParamValueParamProvider$EntityValueSupplier.apply(EntityParamValueParamProvider.java:80)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParamValueFactoryWithSource.apply(ParamValueFactoryWithSource.java:74)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParameterValues(ParameterValueHelper.java:92)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$AbstractMethodParamInvoker.getParamValues(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:133)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:200)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:103)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:493)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:104)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
</pre><p><b>Root Cause</b></p><pre>java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.filter.TokenFilter
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1363)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1186)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._newReader(ObjectMapper.java:640)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.reader(ObjectMapper.java:3323)
    org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.internal.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase._configForReading(ProviderBase.java:489)
    org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.internal.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase._endpointForReading(ProviderBase.java:882)
    org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.internal.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase.readFrom(ProviderBase.java:789)
    org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.invokeReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:257)
    org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:236)
    org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:156)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:73)
    org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:156)
    org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1091)
    org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:874)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest.readEntity(ContainerRequest.java:271)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.EntityParamValueParamProvider$EntityValueSupplier.apply(EntityParamValueParamProvider.java:97)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.EntityParamValueParamProvider$EntityValueSupplier.apply(EntityParamValueParamProvider.java:80)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParamValueFactoryWithSource.apply(ParamValueFactoryWithSource.java:74)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParameterValues(ParameterValueHelper.java:92)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$AbstractMethodParamInvoker.getParamValues(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:133)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:200)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:103)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:493)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:104)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
</pre><p><b>Note</b> The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.</p><hr class="line" /><h3>Apache Tomcat/9.0.20</h3></body></html>
```

Comment: Have you try with @CrossOrigin annotation

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, @crossOrigin is used with spring projects. Can we use it with a Jersey project?

Comment: Ok @Soothran You can add cors in your web.xml file

Comment: @Bagwat thanks for the suggestion. Yes I did that. But it was causing some other error but not related to CORS. Here I believe the issue is with my project setup and not CORS. Because from beginning I was able to send requests with form params successfully. But issue started when I send a request with json

Comment: Remove `jackson-core` dependency, and make sure the `jackson-datatype-json-org` version is the _same_ version as the version pulled in by `jersey-media-json-jackson`. You have a versioning problem with Jackson. There are incompatible versions. `jersey-media-json-jackson` pulls in Jackson. So you need to find out what version and make sure you are using the same version of `jackson-datatype-json-org`

Comment: @PaulSamsotha Sorry for the late reply. I updated `jackson-datatype-json-org` to the latest version. You are right. I am getting the desired output. Thanks a lot. :)